# Installing Apache Web Server

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, installation

Total beginner, but need to run some coldfusion scripts, and from what I gather need to have Apache HTTP server installed along with ColdFusion trial edition to do so. I'm installing Apache HTTP Server 2.2 using the installation wizard, and it's asking for Network Domain and Server Name. Does that require specific information or would just any user generated domain and server name suffice?

Comment: If you are just testing the scripts (not a public webserver) try XAMPP -it comes with a preconfigured copy of Apache and is much easier to setup (guessing you are using Windows if you have a GUI install?)

Comment: Thanks! That does seem much simpler. That said, I've been meaning to start learning about hosting with Apache for a long time and this seemed like just the problem to help me kill my procrastination over it. Could I get away with localhost as both network domain and server name?

Comment: Yes, any values should work - including localhost.

Comment: You may want to consider running this on a virtual machine (e.g. using Virtualbox). Then, by taking snapshots at appropriate points, you can very easily revert back to a known point without having to reinstall if/when you break something. Very handy when you're experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most likely input any information you want. The Network Domain and Server Name are used for error pages, virtual hosts, etc. All of these things you wouldn't be doing for a simple test installation. You can also change them later on.